# Duality in the discrete-time Fourier series

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-series, periodic

Suppose $g[n]$ is periodic with fundamental period $N$ and $f[k]$ being its Fourier coefficients i.e. $$ f[k] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=<N>}g[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$$ In more convenient notation $$g[n]\leftrightarrow f[k]$$  It's easy to prove $$f[n]\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{N}g[-k]$$ This is called "Duality in the discrete-time Fourier series". My problem is applying duality in the case of $$x[n-n_0] \leftrightarrow a_ke^{-jk(\frac{2\pi}{N})n_0}$$ And $$\sum_{r=<N>}x[r]y[n-r]\leftrightarrow Na_kb_k$$
I think for the first case duality should gives$$x[n]e^{jk(\frac{2\pi}{N})m} \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{N}a_{m-k} \tag{1}\label{*}$$ and the second gives $$x[n]y[n] \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{l = <N>}a_lb_{-k-l} \tag{2}\label{**}$$
**Edit:**
Let $g[n] = \sum_{r=<N>}x[r]y[n-r]$ and $f[k] = Na_kb_k$. So according to the mentioned property $$Nx[n]y[n] \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{N}\sum_{r=<N>}a_rb_{-k-r}$$

Dividing by $N$ leads to $\eqref{**}$.
Similarly if $g[n] = x[n-n_0]$ and $f[k] = a_ke^{-jk(\frac{2\pi}{N})n_0}$ I think then $$x[n]e^{-jn(\frac{2\pi}{N})n_0}\leftrightarrow a_{-k - n_0}$$
Let $m = -n_0$ and we have \eqref{*}.

Obviously these results are wrong but I don't know what's my mistake.

This is taken from Signals and systems by Alan V. Oppenheim:
[image]

Comment: But we don't know how you came up with these results, so we can't know what your mistake is.

Comment: @MattL. You're right, sorry for that. I will add the details.

Comment: @MattL. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the references and the definitions given, here is a proof.

Given:
$$x[n] \leftrightarrow a[k], \ and$$
$$y[n] \leftrightarrow b[k]$$

Fourier Series expansion of $x[n]e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nm}$ would be derived as follows:
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}x[n]e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nm}e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk} = \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}(k-m)n} = a[k-m]$$
The factor $\frac{1}{N}$ gets consumed in the definition of Fourier Series coefficients. Therefore, the following relationship can be stated:
$$x[n]e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nm} \leftrightarrow a[k-m]$$

Similarly, for the second case of multiplication in time-domain, you need to figure out that the inverse Fourier Series relation or the synthesis expression will be the following:
$$x[n] = \sum^{N-1}_{k=0}a[k]e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$$
I am not adding the proof of the above which can be easily derived by plugging the expression for $a[k] = \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$ on the RHS.

Then all we are required to do is proving that the inverse Fourier Transform of convolution of $a[k]$ and $b[k]$ would be product $x[n]y[n]$. Which is as follows:
$$\mathcal{FS}^{-1}(a*b)[k] = \sum^{N-1}_{k=0}(a*b)[k]e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk} = \sum^{N-1}_{k=0}( \sum^{N-1}_{l=0}a[l]b[k-l]) e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$$
$$=>\mathcal{FS}^{-1}(a*b)[k] =  (\sum^{N-1}_{l=0}a[l]e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}ln})(\sum^{N-1}_{k=0}b[k-l]e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}(k-l)n})$$
$$=> \mathcal{FS}^{-1}(a*b)[k]  = \mathcal{FS}^{-1}a[k] \mathcal{FS}^{-1}b[k] = x[n]y[n]$$
I have replaced $m = (k-l)$ in the proof above to get $y[n]$.

Hence both the equations (5.69) and (5.71) are true and correctly given in the book.

I think you are trying to use equation (5.67) to prove equation (5.69) and (5.71). That is not correct, because (5.67) is stating Duality of Fourier Series expression between Continuous Time and Discrete Time. Equation (5.69) and equation (5.71) are duality of Shift-Property and Convolution Property. The second reason you cannot use Duality Expression (5.67) is because (5.67) states that if $\mathcal{FS}g[n] = f[k]$, then $\mathcal{FS}f[n] = \frac{1}{N}g[−k]$. That is it takes Fourier Series of the Fourier Series itself assuming $f[n]$ in time-domain. But in (5.69) and (5.71), the time-domain sequences remain $x[n]$ and $y[n]$ only, so (5.67) does not apply here. There are 3 Duality Properties stated in equation (5.67), (5.69) and (5.71). They are not the consequence of one another. They are a consequence of similarity in definition of Continuous time Fourier Series and Discrete Time Fourier Series.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added my attempt. Please check that.

Comment: @S.H.W Why do you think that the DFT of $\sum x[m]y[n-m]$ is $Na_k b_k$? Where are you getting the factor $N$ from?

Comment: It's not DTFT nor DFT. It's discrete-time Fourier series.

Comment: @S.H.W DFS is just periodization of DFT. So, can you add a little bit of of detail on the factor $N$ in the convolution property? I am not sure that the DFS will have that scaling of $N$. It should just be $a_k b_k$.

Comment: I've added the source. Please take a look.

Comment: @S.H.W Thanks for the reference. I went through the section in the book and found that the definition of Fourier Series in that section is given by equation (5.65) as $f[k] = \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}g[n]e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$, which in turn is derived from equation (3.39). I think it will be helpful to mention this in the question, the relation between $f[m]$ and $g[r]$ instead of the picture of the section. I will try changing my answer based on this relation now.

Comment: You're right, thanks for your help.

Comment: @S.H.W Updated my answer to address your questions. Both equations in the book are correct and  I have added a proof for them. You can check where you are missing.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm looking for the mistakes in my derivation using duality. We can prove them directly as you have done it nicely.

Comment: @S.H.W I think you are trying to use equation (5.67) to prove equation (5.69) and (5.71). That is not correct, because (5.67) is stating Duality of Fourier Series expression between Continuous Time and Discrete Time. Equation (5.69) and equation (5.71) are duality of Shift-Property and Convolution Property. The second reason you cannot use Duality Expression (5.67) is because (5.67) states that if $\mathcal{FS}g[n] = f[k]$, then $\mathcal{FS}f[n] = \frac{1}{N}g[-k]$. That is it takes Fourier Series of the Fourier Series itself making $f[n]$ in time-domain. (contd...)

Comment: @S.H.W (contd...) But in (5.69) and (5.71), the time-domain sequences remain $x[n]$ and $y[n]$ only, so (5.67) does not apply here. There are 3 Duality Properties stated in equation (5.67), (5.69) and (5.71). They are not the consequence of one another. They are a consequence of similarity in definition of Continuous time Fourier Series and Discrete Time Fourier Series.

Comment: Are you sure that they are not the consequence of one another? Because it's said that "This duality implies..." and then there are two examples for that.

Comment: @S.H.W They are not 2 examples of the implication of equation 5.67. If I read closely, I think, What that statement says is : Every property of Discrete Fourier Series has a dual. Then these 2 examples are given of the implication that every property has a dual. Like time-shift property and convolution property. I think you should once consider deriving Discrete Fourier Series of $a[n]e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nm}$, you will find that it will be  $\frac{1}{N}x[-k-m]$. And, this is also not because of only (5.67) but a combined consequence of (5.67) and (5.69).

Comment: @S.H.W A very important  and central part of the Duality expressed in equation (5.67) is exchanging time-domain sequence and frequency domain sequence. Given is a DTFS relation between time-domain $g[n]$ and frequency-domain $f[k]$ related by the equation (5.65) $f[k] = \frac{1}{N}\sum g[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$. And, then Dual equation in (5.67) interchanges time-domain sequence and frequency-domain sequence. Equation (5.67) takes DTFS of $f[n]$ and gives the relationship that $\frac{1}{N}g[-k] = \frac{1}{N}\sum f[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$. But, this interchange doesnot happen in 5.69 / 5.71

Comment: It seems my understanding differs from yours. I'm really confused about this. I'm asked to prove, only using duality, $\sum_{r=<N>}x[r]y[n-r]\leftrightarrow Na_kb_k$ implies $x[n]y[n] \leftrightarrow  \sum_{l = <N>}a_lb_{k-l}$. You're saying it's a different duality. So could you explain it more, please? And how can I apply that to my example?

Comment: @S.H.W No, I am saying that this dual relation is not a consequence of (5.67). You are right in saying that $\sum x[r]y[n-r] \leftrightarrow Na_kb_k$ implies $x[n]y[n] \leftrightarrow \sum a_lb_{k-l}$. And this can be proved. All I am saying is that in proving this you donot need equation (5.67). Because, in this convolution duality also there is no exchange of time-domain with frequency domain. Time-domain remains time-domain. Only Convolution exchanges with product. And, that is why it is a different Duality.

Comment: Okay, you're right. So what's that duality? I mean is there any statement for that like (5.67)? So that we can prove the implication using that duality.